# Сохранение элемента html в localStorage и вывод

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Есть метод, который добавляет новые div на страницу.

```
function add_element() {
        var parent = document.getElementById('component');
        var newelem = document.createElement('form');
        var title = document.createElement('input');
        var content = document.createElement('input');
        newelem.appendChild(title);
        newelem.appendChild(content);
        parent.appendChild(newelem);
        save_element();


        function save_element(){
            const parsed = JSON.stringify(parent);
            localStorage.setItem('hiDen', parsed);
        }
    }
        function get_element() {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hiDen'));
        }

    window.add = add_element;
    window.get_el = get_element;
```

html-код в боди

```
<div>
<form>
    <input type="button" id="button_modal" value="Добавить" onclick="modal_open()"/>
</form>
</div>

 <div id="component">
 </div>

<div class="modal" id="modalDialog">
<form method="post" name="modalwindowpush">
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <input type="text" name="content">
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Закрыть" onclick="modal_close()">
<input type="button" value="Сохранить" onclick="add(); get_el()">
</div>
```

Функции javascript прописаны в head (Привожу только одну из них- имеющую значение для ситуцации). Если имеет значение - кнопка "Сохранить" в модальном окне страницы. 
Но после перезагрузки страницы новые div пропадают.
  Что я делаю не так?
  Имеет ли значение, что это JSP-страница?

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь DOM элемент преобразовать с помощью JSON.stringify.
Попробуйте сделать что то подобное:

```
function save_element(){
   const html = parent.innerHTML; //или целиком parent.outerHTML
   localStorage.setItem('hiDen', html);
}
```

Исходя из вопроса, на основе вашего кода:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('component');

function add_element() {
        var newelem = document.createElement('form');
        var title = document.createElement('input');
        var content = document.createElement('input');
        newelem.appendChild(title);
        newelem.appendChild(content);
        parent.appendChild(newelem);
        save_element();

        function save_element(){
            const parsed = parent.innerHTML;
            localStorage.setItem('hiDen', parsed);
        }
    }

function get_element() {
    parent.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('hiDen');
}
//сохраняете ваш элемент
add_element();
//выводите
get_element();
```

Взгляните пример:
[jsfiddle.net/mcuk4avf](https://jsfiddle.net/mcuk4avf)

1. Нажимаете "Добавить элемент"
2. Перезагружаете страницу
3. Нажимаете "Получить элемент" - элемент вставлен
4. Нажимаете "Очистить хранилище"
5. Перезагружаете страницу
6. Нажимаете "Получить элемент" - элемента в хранилище больше нет.
7. Можете повторить пункт 1.

**Обновлено:**

Так как вы сказали, что у вас **JSP-страница**(с этим я вам не помогу), то вы должны понимать, где и как генерируется ваша страница.

Вот ответ почему у вас не работает код:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568167/how-to-display-localstorage-values-on-jsp

Далее вы сами должны переписать ваш код, чтобы обращаться к localStorage в браузере, а не на сервере.

Comment: Cпасибо, но, к сожалению, не помогло...

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что тогда JSON.parse также не нужно использовать. и даже исходя из вашего кода не совсем понятно как вы используете сохраненные данные в localStorage? С какой целью выполняется get_element()?

Comment: Doigrales, конечно, я сразу же get_element() реализовал в таком виде, в каком Вы привели. Но, все равно, не сработало. Я не понимаю... Это уже второй случай, когда мне предлагают решение на javascript на форумах, но оно не срабатывает. Может, дело в настройках среды разработки? И, кстати, вынос var parent за scope функции не позволяет добавить элемент в данном случае.

Comment: Во-первых, ваш код, возможно, вырван из контекста и мы не знаем всех подробностей. Взгляните на работу вашего кода: https://jsfiddle.net/mcuk4avf/ и, по-моему, все прекрасно работает.

Comment: Я выложил контекст из боди html.  Стили оставшиеся функции из head не приводил, чтобы не загромождать.

Comment: Ответ обновил. Старался помочь по максимуму.

Comment: Спасибо. Наверное, действительно, дело в jsp.

Answer (score 0):

А ларчик просто отрывался - Я разворачивал локальный хост. А при взаимодействии клиента с локальным хостом localStorage не работает.
   Прошу прощения за то, что отвлек внимание на такую ерунду.