# Сохранение определенных элементов через localStorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Нужно сохранить черновик заказа в корзине, то есть, чтобы после обновления страницы, выхода из браузера и тд - при новом заходе на страницу заказ оставался неизменным. *Немного не понимаю саму механику, логику, как это можно было бы сделать...* Пытаюсь реализовать через **localStorage** и **JSON**, и этот простенький код:

```
window.addEventListener('unload', () => {

        const listCart = document.querySelectorAll('.oneStuffOfCartClass')
        localStorage.setItem('wholeCartList', JSON.stringify(listCart))

}, false)

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

        console.log('DOMContentLoaded')
        const list = localStorage.getItem('wholeCartList');
        console.log(list)
        const parsedList = JSON.parse(list);
        for ( let i = 0; i < parsedList.length; i++ ) {
             wholeCart.appendChild(parsedList[i])
        }

}, false)
```

Comment: Механика проста. У вас есть форма и при любом изменении формы вы должны получить все её значения->положить в localStorage. При открытии формы если проверить, а есть ли что-то в localStorage и если есть распарсить оттуда данные и вставить в форму.

Comment: @doox911 Спасибо, братик, за ответ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой пример сохранения структуры в товара в `localStorage`:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const products = [...document.querySelectorAll('.product')]
    .filter(node => node.querySelector('input').checked);

  const productToStorages = [];

  products.forEach(node => {
    productToStorages.push({
      id: node.dataset.productId,
      name: node.querySelector('.product__title').textContent.trim(),
      desc: node.querySelector('.product__desc').textContent.trim(),
    });
  });

  // Скопируй
  // localStorage.setItem('productToStorages', JSON.stringify(productToStorages));

  console.log('productToStorages is array:', productToStorages);
  console.log('productToStorages is JSON:', JSON.stringify(productToStorages));
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.product {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="product" data-product-id="1">
    <div class="product__title">
      Товар 1
    </div>
    <div class="product__desc">
      Описание 1
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
  </div>
  <div class="product" data-product-id="2">
    <div class="product__title">
      Товар 2
    </div>
    <div class="product__desc">
      Описание 2
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div class="product" data-product-id="3">
    <div class="product__title">
      Товар 3
    </div>
    <div class="product__desc">
      Описание 3
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>

<button id="btn">Сохранить на будущее..</button>
```

А в вашем случае надо при загрузке страницы вытащить из `localStorage` товары и если они есть подставить их в нужный товар.

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое за такой подробный ответ!!) `const products = [...document.querySelectorAll('.product')]` - что значит троеточие? `node.dataset.productId` - если это поиск по `data-product-id`, то интересно, впервые встречаюсь с таким)

Comment: 1. Это [Деструктуризация](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring). По всему остальному - учите JavaScript. Если ответ решает вашу проблему, прошу отметить как решение.

Answer (score -2):

*Может кому то поможет :)*

**РЕШЕНИЕ:**

Благодаря комментарию **@doox911** - осознал в какую сторону двигаться:

Добавил в `localStorage` все данные из `form`, но товар в корзине, который тоже находился внутри тега `form` не сохранялся - это просто `div` с такими же вложенными элементами, поэтому нужно сохранять по другому... Поискав по сети, нашёл похожий вопрос: [Сохранение элемента html в localStorage и вывод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/915585/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-html-%D0%B2-localstorage-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4)

**Суть которого в этом действии:**

```
const parsed = wholeCart.innerHTML
localStorage.setItem('parsedCart', parsed)

const cartGot = localStorage.getItem('parsedCart')
if (cartGot) {
   wholeCart.innerHTML = cartGot
}
```

Comment: Я не имел в виду хранить `html`. Это жесть) Я имел в виду хранить, например объект, со значениями..

Comment: @doox911 Почему жесть?
Я пробовал сначала через объект, но не мог вытащить оттуда элементы...

Comment: Потому, что это туча лишнего. А если у тебя будет 100 форм со 100 полями? Ты так лимит стораджей исчерпаешь. + вставлять готовый html не безопасно.

Comment: Ааа, понял про что ты) Я не форму через html вставляю, а только теги `div` @doox911

Comment: Это тоже плохо пахнет. Приведи пример данных из стора.

Comment: Storage {phone: '+7 (454) 545 54 54', parsedCart: '<div class="oneStuffOf-cart oneStuffOfCartClass">\n…tyStuff-cart normalLength">Ququ</p></div>', length: 2} @doox911

Comment: Ну да, ковырнул говно... Должен хранится только телефон в объекте или массиве объектов.

Comment: Ахахаха 
Хотел как лучше, а получилось, как обычно :)
@doox911

Comment: Ща накидаю тебе пример